# NodeManager starts and stops in Slave Node

Tags: hadoop

In my 2 node cluster, when I try to run `/start-yarn.sh` it starts NodeManager on both master and slave nodes. But, in slave node, it gets killed after some time. Here is what is found in log file:

```
2014-09-08 13:37:12,224 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeHealthCheckerService is stopped

2014-09-08 13:37:12,224 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.AbstractService: Srvvice:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DeletionService is stopped

2014-09-08 13:37:12,224 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnException: Failed to Start org.apache.hadoop.yarn.se$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.CompositeService.start(CompositeServi$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.start(NodeMana$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNo$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManag$
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredTh$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.star$
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.CompositeService.start(CompositeServi$
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBCl$       
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.regi$       
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.star$       
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Cal$       
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(P$       
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBCl$       
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From slave1/10.255.255.35 to 0.0.0.0$       
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(P$       
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:70$       
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeou$

2014-09-08 13:37:12,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 4
2014-09-08 13:37:12,240 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
2014-09-08 13:37:12,240 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
2014-09-08 13:37:12,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
2014-09-08 13:37:12,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeMana
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at slave1/10.255.255.35
************************************************************/
```

Any help?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?